# How do I resize my Plotly bar height and show only bar’s edge (in subplot)?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

this is my first foray into Plotly. I love the ease of use compared to matplotlib and bokeh. However I'm stuck on some basic questions on how to beautify my plot. First, this is the code below (its fully functional, just copy and paste!):

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly as py
import pandas as pd
from plotly import tools

d = {'Mkt_cd': ['Mkt1','Mkt2','Mkt3','Mkt4','Mkt5','Mkt1','Mkt2','Mkt3','Mkt4','Mkt5'],
       'Category': ['Apple','Orange','Grape','Mango','Orange','Mango','Apple','Grape','Apple','Orange'],
           'CategoryKey': ['Mkt1Apple','Mkt2Orange','Mkt3Grape','Mkt4Mango','Mkt5Orange','Mkt1Mango','Mkt2Apple','Mkt3Grape','Mkt4Apple','Mkt5Orange'],
            'Current': [15,9,20,10,20,8,10,21,18,14],
           'Goal': [50,35,21,44,20,24,14,29,28,19]
     }
dataset  = pd.DataFrame(d)

grouped = dataset.groupby('Category', as_index=False).sum()
data = grouped.to_dict(orient='list')
v_cat = grouped['Category'].tolist()
v_current = grouped['Current']
v_goal = grouped['Goal']
fig1 = px.bar(dataset, x = v_current, y = v_cat, orientation = 'h',
              color_discrete_sequence = ["#ff0000"],height=10)
fig2 = px.bar(dataset, x = v_goal, y = v_cat, orientation = 'h',height=15)

trace1 = fig1['data'][0]
trace2 = fig2['data'][0]
fig = make_subplots(rows = 1, cols = 1, shared_xaxes=True, shared_yaxes=True)
fig.add_trace(trace2, 1, 1)
fig.add_trace(trace1, 1, 1)
fig.update_layout(barmode = 'overlay')
fig.show()
```

Here is the Output:
[image]

Question1: how do I make the width of v_current (shown in red bar) smaller? As in, it should be smaller in height since this is a horizontal bar. I added the height as 10 for trace1 and 15 for trace2, but they are still showing at the same heights.

Question2: Is there a way to make the v_goal (shown in blue bar) only show it's right edge, instead of a filled out bar? Something like this:
[image]

If you noticed, I also added a line under each of the category. Is there a quick way to add this as well? Not a deal breaker, just a bonus. Other things I'm trying to do is add animation, etc but that's for some other time!

Thanks in advance for answering!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `plotly.express` wil return a `plotly.graph_objs._figure.Figure` object. The same goes for `plotly.graph_objects` running `go.Figure()` together with, for example, `go.Bar()`. So after building a figure using plotly express, you can add lines or traces through references directly to the figure, like:

```
fig['data'][0].width = 0.4
```

Which is exactly what you need to set the width of your bars. And you can easily use this in combination with plotly express:

#### Code 1

```
fig = px.bar(grouped, y='Category', x = ['Current'],
             orientation = 'h', barmode='overlay', opacity = 1,
             color_discrete_sequence = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[1:])
fig['data'][0].width = 0.4
```

#### Plot 1

[image]

In order to get the bars or shapes to indicate the goal levels, you can use the approach described by DerekO, or you can use:

```
for i, g in enumerate(grouped.Goal):
    fig.add_shape(type="rect",
                    x0=g+1, y0=grouped.Category[i], x1=g, y1=grouped.Category[i],
                    line=dict(color='#636EFA', width = 28))
```

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly as py
import pandas as pd
from plotly import tools

d = {'Mkt_cd': ['Mkt1','Mkt2','Mkt3','Mkt4','Mkt5','Mkt1','Mkt2','Mkt3','Mkt4','Mkt5'],
       'Category': ['Apple','Orange','Grape','Mango','Orange','Mango','Apple','Grape','Apple','Orange'],
           'CategoryKey': ['Mkt1Apple','Mkt2Orange','Mkt3Grape','Mkt4Mango','Mkt5Orange','Mkt1Mango','Mkt2Apple','Mkt3Grape','Mkt4Apple','Mkt5Orange'],
            'Current': [15,9,20,10,20,8,10,21,18,14],
           'Goal': [50,35,21,44,20,24,14,29,28,19]
     }
dataset  = pd.DataFrame(d)

grouped = dataset.groupby('Category', as_index=False).sum()

fig = px.bar(grouped, y='Category', x = ['Current'],
             orientation = 'h', barmode='overlay', opacity = 1,
             color_discrete_sequence = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[1:])

fig['data'][0].width = 0.4
fig['data'][0].marker.line.width = 0

for i, g in enumerate(grouped.Goal):
    fig.add_shape(type="rect",
                    x0=g+1, y0=grouped.Category[i], x1=g, y1=grouped.Category[i],
                    line=dict(color='#636EFA', width = 28))
f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! however its asking me to install Kaleido when I run this. Wanted to know why because you're not even importing it

Comment: @rustynail I believe it's the same reason why javascript isn't imported. Plotly uses both, but you don't need to import them in a python script.

Comment: Could you explain "x0=g+1, y0=grouped.Category[i], x1=g, y1=grouped.Category[i]" part? I have been looking at the website, but I'm more confused. Why g+1?

also how did you define color_discrete_sequence to be exactly how I showed in my sample? What if I want to pick different colors for different bars, will I be able to do that? Thank you for your answers!

Comment: @rustynail You're welcome! I'd be happy to explain all details in a chat. I don't have the time right now, so I'll send an invite later. And please remind me if I forget to do so.

Comment: @rustynail I've got some time to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230002/room-for-vestland-and-rustynails) now if you're up for it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Plotly Express` and then directly access the figure object as @vestland described, but personally I prefer to use `graph_objects` to make all of the changes in one place.

I'll also point out that since you are stacking bars in one chart, you don't need subplots. You can create a `graph_object` with `fig = go.Figure()` and add traces to get stacked bars, similar to what you already did.

For question 1, if you are using `go.Bar()`, you can pass a width parameter. However, this is in units of the position axis, and since your y-axis is categorical, width=1 will fill the entire category, so I have chosen width=0.25 for the red bar, and width=0.3 (slightly larger) for the blue bar since that seems like it was your intention.

For question 2, the only thing that comes to mind is a hack. Split the bars into two sections (one with height = original height - 1), and set its opacity to 0 so that it is transparent. Then place down bars of height 1 on top of the transparent bars.

If you don't want the traces to show up in the legend, you can set this individually for each bar by passing `showlegend=False` to `fig.add_trace`, or hide the legend entirely by passing `showlegend=False` to the `fig.update_layout` method.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
# from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly as py
import pandas as pd
from plotly import tools

d = {'Mkt_cd': ['Mkt1','Mkt2','Mkt3','Mkt4','Mkt5','Mkt1','Mkt2','Mkt3','Mkt4','Mkt5'],
       'Category': ['Apple','Orange','Grape','Mango','Orange','Mango','Apple','Grape','Apple','Orange'],
           'CategoryKey': ['Mkt1Apple','Mkt2Orange','Mkt3Grape','Mkt4Mango','Mkt5Orange','Mkt1Mango','Mkt2Apple','Mkt3Grape','Mkt4Apple','Mkt5Orange'],
            'Current': [15,9,20,10,20,8,10,21,18,14],
           'Goal': [50,35,21,44,20,24,14,29,28,19]
     }
dataset  = pd.DataFrame(d)

grouped = dataset.groupby('Category', as_index=False).sum()
data = grouped.to_dict(orient='list')
v_cat = grouped['Category'].tolist()
v_current = grouped['Current']
v_goal = grouped['Goal']

fig = go.Figure()

## you have a categorical plot and the units for width are in position axis units
## therefore width = 1 will take up the entire allotted space
## a width value of less than 1 will be the fraction of the allotted space
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=v_current,
    y=v_cat,
    marker_color="#ff0000",
    orientation='h',
    width=0.25
    ))

## you can show the right edge of the bar by splitting it into two bars
## with the majority of the bar being transparent (opacity set to 0)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=v_goal-1,
    y=v_cat,
    marker_color="#ffffff",
    opacity=0,
    orientation='h',
    width=0.30,
    ))

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=[1]*len(v_cat),
    y=v_cat,
    marker_color="#1f77b4",
    orientation='h',
    width=0.30,
    ))

fig.update_layout(barmode='relative')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's a nice approach! But just one thing; Plotly express does ***not*** sacrifice adjustability for ease of coding. I'll write up an answer myself to show you why your statement is not quite correct.

Comment: @vestland sure thing! Now that you mention it, since Plotly express creates graph_objects internally, you can probably still access all of the needed parameters for any figure? I guess my point is that I think plotly.graph_objects is "cleaner" than Plotly express + accessing fig.layout, but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: But I understand that using Plotly express doesn't mean you can't access the necessary parameters- I'll modify my answer so that it's factually correct

Comment: OK! Plotly express does take some time to get used to I guess. I started out with `plotly.graph_objects`, but as I gained experience in accessing and editing the necessary parameters, I moved on to doing the ground work with plotly express and then make the needed adjustments from there.

Comment: Thank you @derekO! Would it make sense to keep Subplots if I want to add x axis under individual category (alluding to my Bonus question :))

Comment: @rustynails Ah I missed that! Yes, absolutely. You can keep the subplots and use minimal padding between the plots to achieve the desired effect. I'll update my answer when time permits

Comment: Thank you so much! In the end I ended up using vestland's code :) but wanted to thank you again for your help, it answered a lot of questions for me.

Comment: @rustynails no problem, my goal is to help people whether my answers are the best or not — i'm glad to hear my contribution was helpful, cheers!